# Converting byte[] to string[] in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a byte array of length 56 and I converted this to String using the function:

```
str = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
```

Now, I need to copy the first twenty characters of "str" into another string "Keydata" or `string[]` and when i use

```
Array.Copy(str, 0, Keydata, 0, 20);
```

I get an error stating

> parameter needs to be `string[]` and not `string`

How do I get past this?

Comment: Why not use `string.Substring` ?

Comment: use `str.Substring(0, 20)` like @Lasse said. If you still want to use `Array.Copy`,  use it like `Array.Copy(new string[] { str }, 0, Keydata, 0, 20)`

Comment: Do you need a string or string[]?

Comment: Error is probably wrong; treating a string as array means you need Char[], not String[]. You can get the char array of a string by using `str.ToCharArray()`. But, yeah, just `str.Substring(...)` seems more sensible here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string anotherString = str.Substring(0, 20);
```

or

```
Array arr = str.Substring(0, 20).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first 20 characters of the string you can simply use the string.Substring method instead, using a starting position and number of characters as parameters:

```
str = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
string first20Chars = str.Substring(0, 20);
```